# Spring session creation policy per-request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

***TL;DR***

**Is it possible to control the session creation policy in Spring (Security) on a per request basis?**

*Long version...*

I have been using normal login form user authentication for our application.
Some of the controllers are @RestControllers and up to now, the default user session tracked by cookie has allowed it to work fine.

(I.e. when an XHR request comes from a page, the request is authenticated to the previously logged in user as the browser sends the JSESSIONID cookie as usual)

I now want to allow some of the @RestController end points to be called from a rest client, rather than browser, so I have created an API token authentication scheme - this works fine.

One of the last bits of cleanup is that the REST calls generate a session, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

I can't set the session policy to NEVER (because i'm still relying on sessions for my web users).

I have tried IF_REQUIRED to no avail.

I have looked at the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository but it wraps the request, and a session is created whenever the response is flushed.

*(See stacktrace below)*

Is it possible elsewhere to hook into the session management on a per-request basis?

I can distinguish the type of request easily enough based on the class type of the `Authentication` object.

```
at myapp.cfg.WebConfig$1.sessionCreated(WebConfig.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.sessionCreated(ApplicationListeners.java:300)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge.sessionCreated(SessionListenerBridge.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.session.SessionListeners.sessionCreated(SessionListeners.java:52)
at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager.createSession(InMemorySessionManager.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:741)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:370)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:270)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.createNewSessionIfAllowed(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:427)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:364)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.doOnResponseCommitted(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:245)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.access$000(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:33)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:512)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:513)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1050)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:953)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Split your security configuration into separate sections for a form login (session based API access) and a stateless API token authentication scheme.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().realmName("API") // your API token authentication scheme 
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("Form realm=\"API\"")); // prevent basic authentication popup in browser
    }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    class DefaultSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }
    }
}
```

Replace `.httpBasic().realmName("API")` with you own authentication scheme.

Call your API with e.g. `curl -v ...` and verify that there is no `Set-Cookie` header in the response. Otherwise your code somewhere creates an http session on its own.

Comment: Thanks Kamill.  This looks like a very good approach.  I'll try it out shortly and report back.

Comment: I've given this a go, but can't seem to find the right configuration.  Having experimented, it seems that only one HttpSecurity chain will be used per request.  The specific http.antMatcher(...) here promotes the APISecurityConfiguration into use.  But as (pretty much) the whole backend can be protected by either session-auth OR session-less api key, I can't work out how to avoid duplicating (and maintaining) the rest of the config.

Comment: @RobShepherd I am also facing same thing. I belive you cannot do above approach because URL for all APIS are same and cannot be distinguished based on URL pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You should try create-session policy as "stateless" for your API end points.

> If "stateless" is used, this implies that the
>                   application guarantees that it will not create a session. This differs from the use of
>                   "never" which mans that Spring Security will not create a session, but will make use of
>                   one if the application does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and could not find a clean solution. In the absence of better options, I'll post a semi working hack.

DISCLAIMER: I have not used this solution (I fell back to sessions, at least for now), try it at your own risk.

Override the default `SecurityContextRepository`:

```
@Component
public class CustomSecurityContextRepository extends HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository {

    @Override
    public SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = super.loadContext(requestResponseHolder);

        // disable automatic saving of security context on response committed
        // WARNING: not sure how safe this is
        SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper response = 
                (SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper)requestResponseHolder.getResponse();
        response.disableSaveOnResponseCommitted();
        return securityContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveContext(SecurityContext context, HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        // call super.saveContext according to your use case
    }
}
```

Finally, register this class in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.securityContext().securityContextRepository(customSecurityContextRepository);
}
```

If anyone has a better solution I would be interested in hearing it.