# Spring security - Specific session creation policy per matchers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

I'm trying to implement `SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS` for the `/testMVCController/**` endpoint and `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` for rest of endpoints (`/**`).

**Expected scenario:**

When accessing to `/testMVCController/displayUsers` the user logs in once and the log I have implemented in UserDetailsService logs the authorities associated to that user.
After that, all the requests to `/testMVCController/displayUsers` or other URL under `/testMVCController/**` will not log the authorities again because the session creation policy is always and the user is already logged in.

This works when I don't specify the 2nd security configuration (`X509ClientSessionCreationPolicyStateless`) but when I add it, all the requests become session stateless.

It is not working with the current security configuration because after I log in with my client certificate, at any request executed under `/testMVCController/**` endpoint (e.g. `/testMVCController/displayUsers`), the authenticationUserDetailsService is consulted and the list of authorities is logged for each file request the browser makes (.js file, .css files, ...), even after the initial login.

So, if there are 3 requests (`/testMVCController/displayUsers`, `displayUsers.js`, `displayUsers.css`) the list of authorities log present in authenticationUserDetailsService is logged 3 times.

I configured SecurityConfiguration as shown below but it is not working:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

 @Configuration
 @Order(1)
 public static class X509ClientSessionCreationPolicyAlways extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Autowired
      private X509CUDService x509CUDService;

      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                .antMatcher("/testMVCController/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .authenticationUserDetailsService(x509CUDService)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
      }

 }

 @Configuration
 @Order(2)
 public static class X509ClientSessionCreationPolicyStateless extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Autowired
      private X509CUDService X509CUDService ;

      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .authenticationUserDetailsService(X509CUDService);
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
      }

      @Override
      @Bean
      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
      }

 }
```

}

I've searched this issue and I found various links (e.g. [Spring session creation policy per-request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523648/spring-session-creation-policy-per-request), [Spring Session: How to create separate session management policies for different URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262262/spring-session-how-to-create-separate-session-management-policies-for-different) and [Multiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity)) but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by '*Spring is always accessing the principal authorities (displayed in the logs)* and where are your logs?

Comment: The authenticationUserDetailsService is consulted at each request made (and I'm logging the authorities list there). In the logs I see this list logged every time I hit an endpoint. But with the session creation policy with the Always value, this list should only be logged once (the first time I choose the client certificate and execute the login action).

Comment: Enable `DEBUG` log for `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` then you will see the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some details on my configuration. I was catching all the requests to `/testMVCController/**` and that was working, but in addition to catch the requests to any endpoint of the type `/testMVCController/**` (e.g.: /testMVCController/usersList), I also have to catch the requests that these pages make to get their scripts (.js files, .css files, .png files).
What was happening was: the request to `/testMVCController/usersList`), was configured with `SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS`, but the subsequent requests such as `usersList.js`, `usersList.css`, etc were configured with `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, and in these cases the `X509CustomUserDetailsService` was always consulted.

Example:
GET request to `/testMVCController/usersList` works, but there also requests in this usersList page to `usersList.js`, `usersList.css`, etc.

So, once I included these resource paths in the antMatchers all worked perfectly.